# Combo box click event not loading remote store

Tags: combobox, extjs5

I have a combo box(with remote store) which needs to be loaded based on two other combo box selected values. So i kept the remote store autoLoad to false. and as soon as second combo value is selected i am loading this combo store.

Till this point it worked well for me.

But my client request is: When the combo box drop down is clicked, it has to reload the remote store based on other two combo values.  So i have tried expand event to load the store whenever the combo box is expanded. After the store is loaded successfully, the expanded combo is loosing the selection and it is not allowing to select any value. I mean when user clicks the drop down it is loosing the focus and dropdown is collapsing automatically. I am sure that the request is sent to server to load the store but combo box expand is not working properly.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?
I really stuck up here.

Thanks,
Valli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer as below:

1) Listen to expand event and send an ajax request to load the store.
2) Once store is loaded successfully set the data to store using store.loadRawData method.